# Get selected value from alertDialog and reload activity in android using the selected value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I am developing an android application that takes the user's location and plots the points around him within a specific radius on the map. The radius is hardcoded to be 30 miles. I use this radius to do an API call to my server which gives me the points to be plotted. So, the radius can be a string here (like "10","15","20" etc)

I am trying to add a settings functionality to it so that the user can change the radius. I am implementing an alertDialog in which I would be displaying the various radius options.

If the user selects a radius from the available ones, the application should reload using the selected radius. Following is the code.

The problem I am facing is that the activity doesnot reload. The application runs fine without any errors but when I go to the settings and click on an radius, it doesent reload the activity. The alertdialog dismisses, but nothing happens.

Note: I have removed the variables declared and other functions from the original code and wrote down only the part which isnt working.
I tried calling the onCreate method but it didnt work. 
I tried using an intent to reload activity as shown below but even that didnot work.

```
//This class implements OnMyLocationChangeListener that is used to 
//display the user's current location on the map 

public class HotspotScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMyLocationChangeListener{


//varibles of the application declared here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.hotspot_screen);

    // I plan to reload the activity by sending the radius string to the activity
    // and then use it to load the activity using the selected radius
    // following is to see if radius is sent while reloading the activity  
    //if yes, using the radius selected.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getStringExtra("start") != null){
        radius = intent.getStringExtra("start");
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Radius: "+radius, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    //this is my function to setup the map
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

}

// following is the code to pop up the alertdialog which gives a list of 
// values for radius for the user to choose.
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hotspot_screen_settings, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.settings:
        settingsMenuItem();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void settingsMenuItem() {
    String[] radius_list = {"10", "15", "20", "25", "30", "35", "40", "45" ,"50"};
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Change radius")
    .setItems(radius_list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            switch(which){
            case 10:
                Intent i = new Intent(HotspotScreen.this, HotspotScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("radius", "10");
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                HotspotScreen.this.finish();
                //HotspotScreen.this.onCreate(null);
                break;
            case 15:
                Intent i = new Intent(HotspotScreen.this, HotspotScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("radius", "15");
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                HotspotScreen.this.finish();
                //HotspotScreen.this.onCreate(null);

                break;
            case 20:
                Intent i = new Intent(HotspotScreen.this, HotspotScreen.class);
                i.putExtra("radius", "20");
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                HotspotScreen.this.finish();
                //HotspotScreen.this.onCreate(null);

                break;
            }
        }
    })
    .show();
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In every case, you need to dismiss the dialog and call the a function via which you're reloading the content of the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the `which` value in the onClick method does not mean your radius value, it is the position of the item been clicked. So try:

```
switch(radius_list[which]){
    case "10":...
    case "15":...
}
```

And personally I think you don't need to reload the activity for this case, you can just set the radius in the switch block and call setUpIfNeeded again to make changes to view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved the problem and I have follower your advice as well. It simplifies the execution a lot. Thankyou so much :)